# Is there a way to get the NSCell object given the row and column indexes of the selected cell a table?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to get the NSCell object given the row and column indexes of the selected cell a table?

I can't use the NSTableView delegate methods, such as `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` because I need to get the cell object in this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

thanks

Comment: While I don't have an immediate answer to your question, I wonder if there is not a way to use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, given that that is the official way of getting there. What is it that you trying to obtain?

Comment: @Monolo I need to call the [cell compare:nil] method in order to display the completion list automatically (and not after pressing F5 or typing something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible try this below :-

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    NSCell *cell=[aTableView preparedCellAtColumn:[aTableView selectedColumn] row:rowIndex];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell);
    return YES;
}
```